# Remove Listeners after emit on click - Advice on Socket.io and Node

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to node and i have been playing while developing an app and so far so good. I am using socket.io with http server. All work as expected but.... i have a button that emit to the socket and after 10 clicks i get a warning on the logs about the event memory leak detected and to setMaxListeners. So far i saw on other questions, i must remove the listeners after emit instead of take the shortcut of increase the Max Listeners, but i have been trying without success.

My client side code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
        $("#validate").click(function () {
            socket.emit('stop', "validate button");
        });
    });
```

On the server side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // WE RECEIVE stop
    socket.on('stop', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);            
        clearInterval(refresh);
    });
});
```

How can i remove the listener after the event?

Any lights will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To only fire the client-side event once, since you are using jQuery, you can use the `one()` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $("#validate").one('click', function () {
              socket.emit('stop', "validate button");
        });
    });
```

On the server-side, try this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // WE RECEIVE stop
    socket.on('stop', stopHandler);

    function stopHandler (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      clearInterval(refresh);
      socket.removeListener('stop', stopHandler);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it limit the click to one execution, the second time i click on it, it do not emit to the socket and i think the listener keep adding to the event anyways.

Comment: I think I better understand your issue now, have a look at the update I made to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, that remove the listener, but the button wont work anymore, i mean what i want to achieve is to avoid keep adding listeners on each click and avoid the memory leak message, the button will be clicked several times, without remove the listeners after 10 clicks will be a warning about the maxListeners, i do not see any memory increases on the server but that warning should not pop up. I dont know if it is possible to emit to the socket, remove the listener and keep waiting for new request, then a new listener is added, emit and then removed , it make sense?

Comment: I think i found the issue, reading the following link http://www.jongleberry.com/understanding-possible-eventemitter-leaks.html i notice i was adding a event to the socket data (msg), as it was used only for debug in the console, on production was not needed, removing it and leaving function() the warning gone away.